# How to use in react app Date Range Picker a JavaScript component for choosing date ranges dates and times?

Tags: reactjs, daterangepicker

I am new in reactjs, but i need to add my project Date Range Picker (A JavaScript component for choosing date ranges, dates and times). I would like to get advice from expert how to do this.

This is the javascript component url : https://www.daterangepicker.com/

Comment: Hi, if you're new to react I would advice you to look for a react component which does that, I don't think trying to interface a jQuery component with a react one would be a beginners task (if you do, you would learn a lot tho). There are  [plenty components to choose from](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&sxsrf=ACYBGNR1E1-QJDIsYWiTyK6rR-uKQJugHQ%3A1573448745686&ei=KezIXaC-KYmf_Qap8LfQAQ&q=react+date+range+picker&oq=react+date+reange+picker&gs_l=psy-ab.3...0.0..3810...0.0..0.0.0.......0......gws-wiz.2-qsWklrbFs&ved=0ahUKEwjg9russeHlAhWJT98KHSn4DRoQ4dUDCAs&uact=5)

Comment: use ant design datepicker.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a beginner then instead of creating new component you can use try existing react component https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-daterange-picker. Also you can have a look on Material UI - https://material-ui.com/components/pickers/. Material UI provides React components for faster and easier web development.

Regards
Gunjan Bothra